# How do I format the card in Google Fusion Tables so that the text/images appear in multiple columns

Tags: css, google-fusion-tables, multiple-columns

I've been trying to separate the text/images into columns using normal CSS script, but they are not recognized by the google custom card interface.  I've noticed that all the commands are a little different stylistically from CSS, though derived from that language as far as I can tell.  I've tried looking for some general reference material on this google variant to solve this issue, but so far have not had any luck.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The card layouts do use standard CSS. We strip out anything that might be a security risk, but it's unlikely you're encountering that. Can you include a link to your table and an example of the CSS you think should be working but is not?

If you'd rather not make your table accessible you can send mail to googletables-feedback@google.com and we can pick up the conversation from there.